# ValueError: could not convert string to float: (large string)

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, pymongo, spyder

Thanks for your helppp!!!! I'm nearly there!
I have a set of data, and I am trying to graph it, for now just against sequential integers, and later once I have this working, against time.

```
for a in Data['result'][:1]:      #only print the first result in the list
        #print a['value']


    Data_clean = a['value'].replace('0,','0.') 
    Data_list = Data_clean.split(',')

T2 = [map(float, x) for x in Data_list]   #turn string into integer so that it                
                                           #can be graphed

print T2
```

but it get the following error

```
  T2 = [map(float, x) for x in Data_list]

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Data_list looks like this

```
[u'-0.04149', u'-0.03866', u'-0.02914', u'-0.02319', u'-0.02027', u'-0.00234', u'0.00564', u'0.01269', u'0.02852', u'0.04648', u'0.05709', u'0.06261', u'0.07325', u'0.08223', u'0.08665']
```

Comment: ps, this is just a snippit of the data, there is more but way to much to put it all up.

Comment: Is your formatting off? Should `T2 = ...` and `print T2` be inside of that for loop?

Comment: Do you need to get convert the strings into Integers or floats in ` T2 = [map(float, x) for x in Data_list]`  ?

Comment: i tried int() but i think its needs to be a whole number for integer to work. These are decimals..... But im not an expert, i just saw that on another stack page

Comment: if you convert those numbers to integers, you will get only `[0,0,0..]`, check my answer, if you need the "integer" behavior anyway, just replace `float` with `int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your target You are trying to convert it into floats (not integers) in a bad.manner, like mixing strategies, you could do this instead:

```
T2 = map(float, Data_list)
#or
T2 = [float(x) for x in Data_list]
```

is this what you want?

Comment: @JackG Accept the answer if it solved your issue please.

Comment: didnt know that was a thing, haha. its accepted now. thanks again